# Hide Specified Payment method if stock is below threshold

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I want to disable a card payment method if a product has the stock below a threshold or is 0 because i have a lot of products that can be put on backorder but i don't want to allow payment by debit or credit card because there have been a lot of clients that canceled the order and payment after placing the order even if it was clearly stated that the product is on backorder.

Does anyone have any idea how i could do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest edit or override of `hookPaymentOption` in your module.

Check for `$this->context->cart->getProducts()`, loop through products and if there's something wrong just `return;`

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution i used after to suggestion from Krystian Podemski

```
        $products = $this->context->cart->getProducts();
        foreach($products as $product){
            //var_dump($product);
            if($product['quantity_available'] == 0){
                return;
            }
        }
```